# Christmas Short story about kids in a school play?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What I remember: young boys, having to sing. Not good at it. Mom is the narrator, I think. She talks of the difficulty of trying to herd her son and others as they don't seem to pay attention to anything. She looks out her back window, sees her son stock still. She goes out to see what's wrong, and he says he hears the "angels bending near the earth, to touch their harps of gold"

Does this ring a bell for anyone? I am guessing mid to late 70s, maybe early 80s. SF&F magazine that my roommate got. Would love to track this down.

Comment: Apart from the boy mentioning that he hears angels (which could have been a hallucination), what makes this story fantasy?

Comment: I assume this is a reference to [It came upon the midnight clear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Came_Upon_the_Midnight_Clear), which includes the lines *From angels bending near the earth to touch their harps of gold".